# hide iframe div within it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

so i have this HTML for example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

 <div>how are you</div>
 <p>whatttt</p>
<div id="main">
<div id="test">
  div content
<br>
<table class="table">
  <thead> </thead>
    <tr>
       <th>
         some header
       </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
       <td> cell </td>
    </tr>
  </table>  
</div>  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

so if i want to load this with i frame but load only the `div class="main"` it will be like this:

`<iframe class="test" src="testing.html" onload="$('body>*',this.contentWindow.document).not('#main').hide();"></iframe>`

what if i want to show only for example : the `div id="test"` or the `table class="table"` that are in the `din class="main"` how can i go deeper to those divs in that main div?

Thanks in advance guys!

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

*For div with id = test within div id = main*

```
this.contentWindow.document).not('#main #test').hide();

<iframe class="test" src="testing.html" onload="$('body>*',this.contentWindow.document).not('#main #test').hide();"></iframe>
```

*For div with class = table within div id = main*

```
this.contentWindow.document).not('#main .table').hide();

<iframe class="test" src="testing.html" onload="$('body>*',this.contentWindow.document).not('#main .table').hide();"></iframe>
```

Comment: Hi again, and thanks for sticking to resolve this issue :) didn't work, i tried this already :(

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can modify the content inside an iframe. You can try loading it into a div instead.

```
$('.test').load('testing.html #main');
```

Replace

```
<iframe class="test"> with <div class="test">
```

Comment: sure you can modify, i can't use you soultion because my testing.html is dynamic so it changes and need to add php to this jquery like: `testing.html?messageid=<? echo $id ?>`